# aligning numpy arrays of word embedding

Tags: numpy, word-embedding, reorderlist

I have two different word embeddings from two different corpora that I want to compare. The problem is that the vectors are not aligned to the same coordinate axes. One way I thought of is to minimize the absolute sum of the difference between commonly used terms, by reordering one of the vectors. But I don't know how should I figure the reordering step out.

For example this is the first vector:

```
array([ 0.10757965, -0.42568704,  0.98631775, -0.8689575 , -0.15464744,
        0.63064075, -0.7297094 ,  1.1489053 , -0.8563999 ,  3.0642095 ,
        2.7397413 , -0.46641126,  0.1275141 , -1.3700885 , -1.072934  ,
       -0.39100915, -1.671539  , -2.4915023 , -0.35404372, -0.43653855,
       -0.6003148 ,  0.4358256 , -0.9136539 , -1.4925014 ,  0.79358363,
       -1.667434  , -0.6276153 ,  0.3108001 ,  1.3591683 ,  1.759436  ,
        2.322402  ,  1.0543864 , -0.05373017,  0.9086741 , -0.6732362 ,
       -0.26082084, -0.74347293, -0.43117926,  1.5836681 ,  1.431517  ,
       -1.492048  , -0.60741377,  0.995547  ,  2.5840738 , -0.49356472,
       -1.298395  ,  0.9130318 , -0.49302715,  1.6769395 , -0.06804854,
        1.9372663 , -0.47315896, -0.54298705, -1.7971836 ,  0.2661831 ,
        2.8773577 ,  0.9101723 ,  0.8329754 , -0.9257539 , -1.486911  ,
        1.649872  , -0.5530765 ,  3.2154553 ,  1.0755832 ,  0.5363964 ,
       -1.6587971 ,  1.2707052 ,  0.03430567, -0.24029787, -0.9271764 ,
       -0.6114223 , -1.4572513 , -1.0918219 ,  1.7637787 , -0.9404495 ,
        0.0857285 , -0.36915302, -1.7384651 , -0.84735996, -0.8769372 ,
       -0.27842158,  0.03236938,  0.03284004,  0.57761943, -0.5666807 ,
        0.36499354,  3.0521092 ,  0.9019006 , -2.0668502 ,  0.6560068 ,
       -1.4445753 , -0.389482  , -0.47697067,  0.69996965,  2.4705417 ,
       -2.041891  , -0.44354537,  1.4558276 , -0.4295767 , -0.90321654],
      dtype=float32)
```

and this is the second:

```
array([ 1.1058452 , -2.2796783 ,  0.84442025, -1.4999441 , -2.3308396 ,
        1.4135216 , -0.29184476,  0.8679573 ,  0.42321455, -0.74537545,
        1.0027156 , -0.3483125 , -0.7295568 ,  0.6986356 ,  1.1127443 ,
       -1.1311445 ,  1.2409385 , -1.4786898 , -1.3950868 , -0.27554244,
        0.20782918,  1.6640444 , -0.5691695 , -1.4855943 ,  1.1672127 ,
       -1.2179123 ,  0.61364645,  2.5219076 ,  2.1517315 ,  1.0354927 ,
       -0.9716307 ,  1.5431366 , -1.1036105 , -0.18341443,  0.17259996,
       -2.1558301 ,  0.29899794, -0.5547018 , -0.5943715 ,  0.04390683,
        0.560267  ,  0.7034724 , -0.95176893,  2.8047779 ,  0.35110566,
       -0.7586705 ,  1.0484697 , -1.2169212 ,  1.1784345 , -0.35868016,
       -0.76162195,  0.48639485, -0.21598862, -3.1810286 , -0.40469247,
        0.37047744, -1.2177219 ,  1.0136344 , -0.71124744,  0.55197966,
        1.1838216 ,  0.36200544,  0.6969087 , -0.40792528,  0.9196224 ,
       -0.17401141,  1.9862353 ,  0.6656883 , -0.23861286,  1.0554594 ,
        1.9458885 ,  0.840771  , -2.2205007 , -0.10964899, -2.991086  ,
        2.0690446 , -0.01081265,  0.03285171,  0.6332232 ,  0.02735673,
       -2.4799051 ,  0.48361468,  0.4993206 , -1.5299852 , -0.1030245 ,
        2.4105816 , -0.3814318 , -0.14402314, -1.6633567 ,  2.5273507 ,
       -0.72380215,  2.1811585 ,  1.5535759 , -0.8867029 , -0.5552864 ,
       -1.0396701 ,  0.00605698, -0.37520123, -1.8625914 , -1.4351071 ],
      dtype=float32)
```

Now suppose that I have tens of pairs like these:

```
[(v1, v2), (v1, v2), ... (v1, v2)]
```

I want to minimize:

```
np.sum(np.abs(v1 - reordered(v2))
```

on all the pairs of `(v1, v2)`, where `reordered` is a function that reorders the second vector.

Answer (score 2):

Reordering of rows and columns is, indeed, one method to get them to align better without changing the meaning.

It's the equivalent of flipping one piece of paper to make the markings on it align with those on a different sheet, proving that both are maps leading to the same chest of gold.

But that won't be enough if, say the maps have different scales, or if one uses the Mercator projection and the other one doesn't.

Multiplication of an entire embedding matrix by a constant, or by a vector of the embedding's dimension also preserves the information content, as long as you don't multiply by 0. In theory, **if both embeddings are identical, you could just stick them together, making one 600D embedding from two 300D ones, then use Gauss' Algorithm solving it as a system of equations, and the redundancy will result in a bunch of dimensions being eliminated as column of 0.**

That would actually combine the information. To better align them, pick a bunch of word vectors from one embedding and try finding the projection (multiplication) that minimises their distance from the same words' vectors in the the second embedding.

Consider two cubes, and you get to rotate them and, if necessary, make enlarge or shrink them, proportionally. You can always get two points in each embedding to be in exactly the same spots. If the embeddings are similar, this should also reduce the sum of pairwise distances for all other vectors.

But, yes, you'd want to try to use some larger sample of word vectors to align to minimise sensitivity to specific idiosyncrasies, and there won't be an exact solution for that problem. Unfortunately, that's also exactly the point where I don't quite remember what, if any, method or algorithm is used. But even trial & error, or some gradient descent improvisation should give you something meaningful.